# Hovered background color change breaks simulated + display

Tags: css, button, background, hover

I have a button with + and - symbols made with linear gradients and background size. If I add a hover state, just changing the color, the + and - effect doesn't work. Any idea why this happens?

This is the pen: https://codepen.io/miguelrivero/pen/gOraZaM

```
.AddToBagButton__decrease,
.AddToBagButton__increase {
  background: linear-gradient(#2e8561, #2e8561) top left,
    linear-gradient(#2e8561, #2e8561) top right,
    linear-gradient(#2e8561, #2e8561) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(#2e8561, #2e8561) bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 13px solid #2e8561;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  &:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(#215e45, #215e45) top left,
      linear-gradient(#215e45, #215e45) top right,
      linear-gradient(#215e45, #215e45) bottom left,
      linear-gradient(#215e45, #215e45) bottom right;
    border: 13px solid #215e45;
  }
}
.AddToBagButton__decrease {
  background-size: 100% calc(50% - .5px);
  left: 0;
}
.AddToBagButton__increase {
  background-size: calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% - .5px);
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why this happens?

Because you are overwriting the `background-size` you specified for the buttons, by applying the changed gradient via the `background` shorthand property, which resets all *individual* background properties you did not specify, to their defaults. (`.AddToBagButton__decrease:hover` has a higher specificity, than `.AddToBagButton__decrease`.)

Make that

```
&:hover {
    background-image: …
```

instead. (Gradients are considered *images* in CSS.)